# Error with google adsense js on my computer

Tags: google-chrome, adsense

It seems like I have an issue with google adsense as the ads are not displaying on chrome nor firefox on my computer but they are displaying on opera when it's on vpn. I tried this with both wifi and mobile 3G data but I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1
```

Note:

- I previously had adblock on chrome but I uninstalled it long ago so it shouldn't be the reason
- I removed and re-installed google chrome
- I never used firefox before (so there's no adblock on it)
- When I use 3G mobile data, the ads still don't show on my computer but do show on my phone (android google chrome)
- I have this same error message on all websites I access even if it is not mine

Comment: My guess you have ad blocker on network level. Router or some kind of firewall rejects all requests to pagead2.googlesyndication.com domain.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of issue:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID 
//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js
```

Found that this was due to VPN blocking //pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js since it thinks we are accessing a site that is not authorized to be used

So regardless of AdBlock or without AdBlock, we will see the adblock message.

Not sure if you are facing same issue but it would be good to check your firewall/company vpn if any.